# How to transparent status bar on kitkat with Toolbar and NavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

i'm trying to get this beautifull design on my app(running `Kitkat`) on other activities this code is working :

```
 public static class AppUtils {

        public static void setTitleBarTint(Activity ac) {

            ac.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(ac);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintDrawable(ac.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kitkat_status_bar));


        }
    }
```

But on my `MainActivity` with `navigationview` and coordinator layout and others, this code is not working and missed the toolbar.

Of course i've already tryied every tutorials like:

http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

or others..., but, nothing is worked !

**Styles:**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

Is there any solution for solve this?

Comment: have you try to set margin top?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i've edited the question and added what you said, check please.and also, status bar hasn't any Translucent

Comment: i've check it with changing to : `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"`and it's working on **+ 21api** but, this is my output in kitkat:http://i.imgur.com/53yQki6.png so, what do i need to do ?

Comment: Sorry. I meant values-v19/styles.xml Make it there